Two of my transactions were not completed
Two of my transactions were not completed but I was charged for them. How do I get the fees back? It's around $25.

What do you mean by "not completed"? Do you mean failed? Which network? Which transaction ids? Transactions failed have to pay the transaction fee. Once transactions are finalized they cannot be reversed.
